# Can't delete a swap partition, says that it's mounted while swapon says it's not?

Tags: mount, swap

I have a swap partition mounted on `/dev/sda6` Linux Mint 17.2/Windows 10 dual boot.
Am using HP 2000 notebook PC with 4GB RAM. When I installed Linux Mint I created a swap partition which as it happens I never use. I need to delete the swap and free up the 2GB space for my other partitions.

this is the output for `sgdisk --print /dev/sda`:

```
***************************************************************  
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B84ECCAF-EAC2-414C-B6C1-9782B1A75BDF
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 10221 sectors (5.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          206847   100.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2          206848       122882047   58.5 GiB    0700  Microsoft basic data
   3       122882048       737282047   293.0 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   5       737284096       897077247   76.2 GiB    0700  Microsoft basic data
   6       897079296       901076991   1.9 GiB     8200  Linux swap
   7       901079040       976771071   36.1 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
```

[image: This is the error message from gparted]

This is the output from `swapon -s`:
`Filename               Type        Size    Used    Priority`
  I think its blank??

Comment: 1) Turn off swap 2) Remove corresponding entry from `/etc/fstab` 3) Remove partition using your favourite tool, e.g. `gparted`

Comment: I tried using gparted to delete after steps 1 and 2. Its says I have to unmount a partition that is higher than `/dev/sda6` which in this case is `/dev/sda7` my boot partition

Comment: Please provide the output of `swapon --show=name` and `sgdisk --print /dev/sda`.

Comment: Take a look at your grub kernel boot command line too. If you are going to delete definitely your swap volume, take care of remove it from here. Check it out at: `# cat /etc/default/grub` or `# cat /proc/cmdline`. Otherwise, the system will not start after reboot.

Comment: @Marco I edited the post to include the outputs.... Sorry for the late reply, and am still learning the formatting of posts.

Comment: @Marco Am unable to display the output of `swapon --show=name`

Comment: @Arden What do you mean by “unable to display”? You get an error? You get no output? I just want to confirm that swap is not used and correctly turned off. From your output it appears you're not using GPT (which I assumed you did), so you might have a chance to delete the partition with `parted` or `fdisk`. If not, please post the exact error message you receive from a partition tool like `parted`, `gparted` or `fdisk`.

Comment: @Marco `swapon --show=name` requires more arguments. It displays the help message

Comment: @Arden Then you're using a different version, try `swapon -s`. And thanks for adding all the additional info.

Comment: The partition number will be reordered, that's why the messages appear. That's no problem if you use labels or UUID's in your `/etc/fstab`, but it will be if you're using the devices directly. It's best to boot a live distro from USB stick, delete the partition and possibly modify the `/etc/fstab`. As I said, preferrably use the UUID as first field (fs_spec). And – of course – make sure you have a working backup in case the modifications fail for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32455/discussion-between-arden-and-marco).